# What/who is a 'guy with camera' or 'GWC?

Tags: terminology

Recently (mainly) in the hobbyist model photography world I've been hearing the term 'Guy with camera' or 'GWC' thrown around, usually in a derogatory way, by models, photographers and other creatives.

What exactly is a 'guy with camera'. How does it differ from [Uncle Bob](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94238/who-or-what-is-an-uncle-bob)? Is it the same in every country?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the UK at least 'A Guy with Camera' or GWC, is a stereotype of the 'dark side' of photography. A GWC is someone who not necessarily owns a camera for the sake of but usually attends group shoots and shoots models as an excuse to see (usually) young ladies in a varying state of undress. (GWC, can also refer to 'gal/girl with camera', but the stereotype is guy, so GWC is technically non gender specific!).

Although not necessarily a danger, they can be initially identified by:

- Lack of improvement and development of skills (and desire to learn)
- An eagerism to shoot higher levels; implied, nude, topless, erotic, adult etc.
- Inappropriate behaviour, both on and offline, such as lewd comments about models appearances and sexualising the experience.
- Awkward instructions which may not present a model in a flattering way.
- A lack of interest in the 'art' and technicalities of photography, framing, exposure retouching etc, more take as many pictures as possible.

Over time however a GWC may develop their skills and become a competent photographer, and even transition away from being a GWC. If they overstep the boundary and go from 'they're ok but a bit pervy' it can become a serious legal matter.

Some models are OK working with GWCs and find them a necessary part of the job that pays the bills. As long as they have good references and are respectful, they have no issue, they can be seen in a similar vein to an amateur or a beginnner.

As of Uncle Bob, a GWC can be an Uncle Bob, but doesn't necessarily have to be an Uncle Bob.

On a side note, whilst searching for this topic I did find [this article](https://racheljay.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/gwc-whats-it-mean/) which is a perspective from the US which is very similar but a bit harsher, although this line sums it up quite well.

> Often times, the GWC doesn’t give a hoot about photography, bettering
>   his work as a photographer, or actually achieving anything as a
>   photographer.

Comment: Today I learned

Comment: I think this answer is a little too lenient with inappropriate, creepy behavior. Particularly, I think the "over time, transition away" focuses too much on "develop their skills" and not nearly enough on "learn how to act as a respectful human being". And, "some models are okay" could use some citations and references.

Comment: As a contrast I have an anecdote told to me by one of my ad-photo mentors. This gentleman served as the principle photographer for Victoria Secret's catalog images several years running (certainly a GWC's dream.) He related that due to the need to remain professional as well as just sheer exposure he became so desensitized that it was not until several weeks afterwards that he regained the ability to find a woman physically attractive.

Comment: @mattdm in the UK, if you're exposed as a creep you're chastised and that's it. Blacklisted. I'll add something about inappropriate behaviour though as I did miss that out. Citation will be hard to get... it involved a discussion with a few freelance models and alcohol at a party #livingtheduranduranlifestyle

Comment: I know of a pro that sets up workshops to teach lighting and model photography. Mostly I think he's just realized he can easily get money from GWC's. I'm not sure how he convinces the models to go in on the job though

Comment: @Corey for most freelance models it's money at the end of the day, plus it can lead to future bookings. it's just going through the motions. I'm sure not everyone attending workshop is a GWC though. I still attend the occasional one to learn new things!

Comment: @Hueco there seems to be no shortage of models for actual, bona fide porn, why should the situation be different there?